# How to selectively import Bootstrap components in Angular without breaking the package?

Tags: angular, import, sass, bootstrap-5

**Problem description:**

I'm using Bootstrap v5.2 in my Angular project. I want to reduce the package size and loading time by only importing the specific Bootstrap components I need. However, when I try to import individual components like buttons or carousels, I get errors like "Undefined variable."

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Installed Bootstrap using `npm i bootstrap`.
2. Added `@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";` to my styles.scss file. This works, but it includes the entire Bootstrap package.
3. I tried importing individual components like, `@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons.scss";`, but it throws errors.

**What I'm expecting:**

To be able to selectively import specific Bootstrap components without breaking the package.

**What I'm actually getting:**

Errors like "Undefined variable" when importing individual components.

**Additional information:**

I'm using Angular CLI version 16.2.0.

you can find a copy of my project [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/amazing-williams-3d43jq?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i4000a356ivhadnj15%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40003356i7v2uz58c%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40008356i9mwal37b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40009356i3y7pbj8v%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clomof6i40003356i7v2uz58c%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40003356i7v2uz58c%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clomoilz500qm356i0dq2honx%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40002356i9zpf2oq8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fapp.component.html%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomogfub008g356i2ndronbi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Ftest%252Ftest.component.html%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomohq4200gk356i98iwh5tz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomohw4900kl356iq5j4khlr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fapp.module.ts%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomoilz500qm356i0dq2honx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clomof6i40009356i3y7pbj8v%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40009356i3y7pbj8v%2522%257D%252C%2522clomof6i40008356i9mwal37b%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40008356i9mwal37b%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clomoffzm004x356iviyqmdud%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40004356i7rzxppor%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40005356io5r3jhia%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40006356i3t8j1umc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522test%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomof6i40007356ix1cvs9s4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522help%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomoffzm004x356iviyqmdud%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clomofgca01oyedlxfgdvbyes%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

```
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined variable.
  ╷
7 │   --#{$prefix}btn-padding-x: #{$btn-padding-x};
  │       ^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_buttons.scss 7:7  @import
  src\styles.scss 3:9                            root stylesheet
```

and this is my output

It seems like there's an issue with variable scoping when I try to import specific Bootstrap components individually.

I want to achieve the goal of using only selected Bootstrap components while avoiding errors like the one mentioned above. Additionally, I'm concerned about how to manage customization and potential issues when I need to use other Bootstrap components in the future.

Is there a way to include specific Bootstrap components without encountering these errors? How can I efficiently customize Bootstrap for my Angular project to keep the package size minimal while ensuring future scalability?

Any help or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As many of the bootstrap components need to inherit the base styles, they have the bootstap.scss import in place and hence most of the time you will not be able to use them without having bootstrap.scss.

[image: Most of the components depend upon the base bootstrap.scss]

Please refer: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#importing

In angular you will not be able even install the separate individual bootstrap component package without bootstrap base.